# How to calculate distance between 3 geographic points?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates

I am trying to calculate the distance between two geographical points (lat1,lon1), (lat2,lon2). I know this can be done using the formula below, but how do you incorporate 3 geographic points (lat1, lon1, depth1), (lat2, lon2, depth2)?

Comment: formula below ? and distance between three points is a concept I've never heard of.

Comment: I think OP means distance between two points, and each point is a triplet, i.e. Coordinates in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Depth means altitude? If so,</strike>how accurate do you want to calculate?

**EDIT**
*assuming you want to expand spherical liner interpolation instead of trilinear interpolation of 3d-grid*
Because most of the case zero-altitude distance is quite larger than altitude itself, so normally you can ignore altitude. And even [geo distance formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)  doesn't return exact value, because radius of the earth is not same in measurement points.

If the zero-altitude distance is not so large, you can simply calculate like this.

```
//pseudo code
D0 = zero_altitude_distance(lat0,lon0,lat1,lon1)
Distance_you_want = sqrt(pow(D0,2),pow(abs(depth1-depth0),2)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. For depth I meant ocean depth, therefore there is 3 data points I want to consider when calculating the distance between coordinates and also the dimension of depth.

Comment: Ok, anyhow my answer is still same, just consider depth equals minus altitude. Most of the case the approximation formula is enough.